# Display number in pine script

Tags: pine-script

Why is `str.format` display different number than `str.tostring` in this code?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test number", overlay = true)
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.format("{0,number}", high) + "\n" + str.tostring(high))
```

[image: chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `str.format()` with `number` argument, it will round the number.

Below are some examples so you can see it more clearly.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test number", overlay = true)
if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, high, str.format("{0,number}", high) + "\n" + str.format("{0,number, #.#}", high) + "\n" + str.format("{0,number, #.##}", high) + "\n" + str.format("{0,number, #.###}", high) + "\n" + str.tostring(high))
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you! Can you somehow get `str.format` to display the whole number without knowing the precision?

Comment: Why don't you use `str.tostring()` then?

Comment: Ok, ofc it works but cleaner code if only `str.format` is used, if I also have other things to show

Comment: In my opinion, if you want to display the number as it is, you don't need `str.format()`. As the name suggests, it is there to format the input string. You might create a function if you want clean code. Maybe that will help. I don't think it is possible to tell `str.format()` not to round.